# copy cell contents E1 to E2 if C1=C2 Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a monster spreadsheet that has codevalues in column C and display values in column E. Each display value is only shown once per code value and i need it in every row.

is it possible using VBA to copy the cell contents of E2 to E3 if C2 = C3 as in to update the blank to the correct value?

so if C2=C3 then copy B2 to B3???

heres a subset of the 32000 rows i need to cross check against another domain

```
   C (code value)              E(display)
2  83732063  Red Cell Ferritin-SCH    
3  83732063    
4  83732067  Plasma Volume-SCH    
5  83732071  Acylcarnitine Level-SCH    
6  83732071     
7  83732075  Carnitine Total Level-SCH    
8  83732075   
9  83732079  Creatine Level-SCH    
10 83732083  Gamma Aminobutyrate Lvl (CSF/Urine)-SCH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
on error resume next

with worksheets("sheet1").columns("E")
    with .specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks)
        .formular1c1 = "=if(rc[-2]=r[-1]c[-2], r[-1]c, text(,))"
    end with
    .value = .value
end with

on error goto 0
```

Comment: as per OP's example, it seems all column E blanks correspond to a match in column C with the upper cell. should this be true then it could be `.formular1c1 = "=r[-1]c"`. And I'd move `.value = .value` inside `With .specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks) ... End With` block

Comment: While the op's sample data followed that structure, it wasn't mentioned in the narrative so I decided not to assume the fact. No, moving the value write inside the with ... end with block is not viable with intermittent specialcells.

Comment: @Jeeped _"moving the value write inside the with ... end with block is not viable with intermittent specialcells. "_ , right: I always have to bump into it and recall it...